# Spring Passing request parameter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to pass parameter (a String value) to spring controller from a jsp
What is the best or recommended way to do it.
-I don't want to send parameters in URL - @RequestParam may not be suitable
-Should I hook the parameter to a model object and use @ModelAttribute. What if I want just a string value to be passed.. should I create a object with just a string attribute for this purpose?
-Use HttpSevletRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@RequestParam` - it will work with both GET and POST requests. So if you don't want to send them in the URL, use the `POST` method to submit your form.

Comment: <form:form id="updateTicket" method="POST">

 <input id="ticketId" value="2"/>

</form:form>
 @RequestMapping(value="/updateTicket.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String showUpdateTicketForm(@RequestParam("ticketId") String ticketId) { ---- For this I am getting a Status 400 when I submit the form